# DataTable Uncaught TypeError: column is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Table Headings

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th rowspan="2">Project</th>
        <th rowspan="2">Status</th> 
        <th colspan="2">Features</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Passing</th>
        <th>Failing</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

JS Code

```
$('#projectstable').DataTable({
    "ajax":{
       url: "api/projects",
       "dataSrc": ''
     },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "title" },
        { "data": "status" },
        { "data": "features" , render: "passed"},
        { "data": "features" , render: "failed"},
    ]
});
```

Sample data

```
[{
        "id": "demo",
        "title": "demo project",
        "features": {
            "passed": 1,
            "failed": 0,
            "skipped": 0,
            "wip": 0
        }
}]
```

It gives `Uncaught TypeError: column is undefined` in console. Now if I replace `columns` with `column` then it gives following error in alert

```
DataTables warning: table id=projectstable - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

Comment: You're defining 4 columns, yet the HTML has only 3

Comment: Table header has 2 rows. 3rd column has 2 columns which are in 2nd row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this error comes when there are extra columns in the HTML but relevant column is not present in data source. It's is not related to `columns` property of dataTable.
Second error comes when any of the property is not present in data source, null, or undefined. So I need to handle it using `render`.

```
{ 
    "data": "status", 
    render: function(data, type) {
       if(!data) return "";
    }
}
```